# Unknown function 'genai.vector.encode'

Tags: neo4j, neo4j-apoc

I am using neo4j community version on ubunutu. I have Neo4j version 5.18. While invoking the genai function, I am getting error message "Unknown function 'genai.vector.encode'". could you please help me from where I can download the required jar file to enable the plugin

Answer (score 1):

The GenAi plugin for Neo4j is only available for the enterprise version of Neo4j, which can be seen in the top right of the [genAI integrations page](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/genai-integrations/) it is marked as "Enterprise Edition".

As a partial replacement, you can use the APOC extended plugin to create embeddings or get completions. Information on how to install it and use the plugin can be found here: https://neo4j.com/labs/genai-ecosystem/apoc-genai/

It's important to note that you also need to install [APOC](https://neo4j.com/labs/apoc/).

Answer (score 0):

Actually the genai plugin are supported in Neo4j version 5.18,

you will find the jar file named"*neo4j-genai-plugin-5.18.0*" in your n4j directory  **<NEO4J_HOME>/products** ,moved this jar file to **<NEO4J_HOME>/plugins** so that you can enable it.

You'll find more information for genai plugin in this  [site](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/genai-integrations/)

Comment: This folder is not available in neo4j community edition. Is there any way to download it externally